# How to count all the negative numbers in a list

Tags: python

I am trying to run the count function on an array within a for loop, specifically I am trying to find the no. of negative integers within an array. Here's the code I am using:

```
a = (-1, 1, 2, 6, -9, -20, 0, 0, 12, -7, 9, 8, 3, -16)
for i in a:
    print(a.count(i<0))
```

However, the result I get is:

```
1,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,1
```

I wanna know if there is a way to get the counter using the count function inside a for loop and if I am doing something wrong?

I am trying to count all the negative numbers in the array

Comment: What exactly are you expecting `a.count(i<0)` to mean?

Comment: I want to count the numbers in the array that are less than 0

Comment: Okay, and do you want the function to tell you the answer right away, or do you want to use the loop somehow? Try to explain the process you want to follow.

Comment: I want the funciton to tell me the answer right away, I can do it by creating a counter inside an if loop but  was wondering if there was an easier way to do it using a count function within the for loop?

Comment: `list.count` counts a ***specific element***. When you do `count(i<0)` it simply counts the amount of either `True` or `False` in the list

Answer (score 1):

The below should work for you:

```
a = [-1, 1, 2, 6, -9, -20, 0, 0, 12, -7, 9, 8, 3, -16]
neg_count = sum(1 for x in a if x < 0)
print(neg_count)
```

Output
:

```
5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```py
counter = 0
for i in a:
  if i<0:
    counter +=1
print(counter)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list full of `True` and `False` for each number then count how many `True` is in it:

```py
a = (-1, 1, 2, 6, -9, -20, 0, 0, 12, -7, 9, 8, 3, -16)
# Create a list with True or False depending of the condition n<0
neg_list = [n<0 for n in a]
# Count how many True is in the list
print(neg_list.count(True))
# 5
```

Or, you can create a list with each number lower than 0, then count how long the list is:

```py
a = (-1, 1, 2, 6, -9, -20, 0, 0, 12, -7, 9, 8, 3, -16)
print(len([n for n in a if n<0]))
# 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try for example:

```py
a = np.asarray([-1, 1, 2, 6, -9, -20, 0, 0, 12, -7, 9, 8, 3, -16])
np.sum(a<0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `filter`:

```py
a = [-1, 1, 2, 6, -9, -20, 0, 0, 12, -7, 9, 8, 3, -16]
len((list(filter(lambda x: x < 0, a)))) # 5
```

Or `map`:

```
sum(map(lambda x : x < 0, a)) # 5
```